# Every time my TC-agent docker image runs, it's received as a new and unique buildagent

Tags: docker, teamcity

We've set up an Amazon EC2 agent, which on startup runs an image based on the [`jetbrains/teamcity-minimal-agent` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-minimal-agent/) (tag 2020.2.1). The agent is activated and deactivated by a TeamCity Cloud Profile.

Everything is working well, except: every time the agent is started, the TeamCity server registers it as a "new" agent (belonging to the same cloud image). Pretty quickly, we've got dozens of distinct, "different" agents, all in the same cloud profile.

Here's our cloud profile listing, full of agents:

[image: Cloud profile with 34 agents]

And here's a list of some of those agents -- identical names, plus an incrementing counter:

[image: "Unauthorized agents" list keeps getting longer]

**Here's the docker command we're running on machine startup:**

```
docker run -d -it -e SERVER_URL=$OUR_URL -e AGENT_NAME="Software-Linux-dockerAgent-01" \
    -v /home/ubuntu/ci_agent/agent_config:/data/teamcity_agent/conf \
    -v /home/ubuntu/ci_agent/work:/opt/buildagent/work \
    -v /home/ubuntu/ci_agent/system:/opt/buildagent/system \
    my_linux_ci_agent:1.4
```

Server logs show that each time the agent connects, it "has no name defined", and so a new name is generated for it.

```
[2021-01-17 15:13:44,401]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Set generated name "Software-Linux-EC2-Agent-01-i-09307d6796743bda4-2" to agent "" {id=66} as it had no name defined.
[2021-01-17 16:29:54,529]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Set generated name "Software-Linux-EC2-Agent-01-i-09307d6796743bda4-3" to agent "" {id=67} as it had no name defined.
[2021-01-17 23:21:29,798]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Set generated name "Software-Linux-EC2-Agent-01-i-09307d6796743bda4-4" to agent "" {id=68} as it had no name defined.
[2021-01-18 09:27:10,853]   INFO -    jetbrains.buildServer.AGENT - Set generated name "Software-Linux-EC2-Agent-01-i-09307d6796743bda4-5" to agent "" {id=69} as it had no name defined.
```

**What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?**

---

Just a little more info about what I've checked and tried so far.

I would expect that agent configuration data by preserved in the `/data/teamcity_agent/conf` volume, and this should be enough that on the next run, the agent is "recognized."
I can see that `agent_config/buildAgent.properties` does indeed record the name and authorization token assigned by the server:

```
## The unique name of the agent used to identify this agent on the TeamCity server
## Use blank name to let server generate it.
## By default, this name would be created from the build agent's host name
name=Software-Linux-EC2-Agent-01-i-09307d6796743bda4-9

(...)

## A token which is used to identify this agent on the TeamCity server for agent authorization purposes.
## It is automatically generated and saved back on the first agent connection to the server.
authorizationToken=eb0b786556d8f12c1c8917cb10dfdd14
```

But the next time the docker image is started, this is overridden with new values:

```
## The unique name of the agent used to identify this agent on the TeamCity server
## Use blank name to let server generate it.
## By default, this name would be created from the build agent's host name
name=Software-Linux-EC2-Agent-01-i-09307d6796743bda4-10

(...)

## A token which is used to identify this agent on the TeamCity server for agent authorization purposes.
## It is automatically generated and saved back on the first agent connection to the server.
authorizationToken=f966d0c9f6e44fe284243edd19cfba69
```

---

I've found one similar post on the TeamCity community forum, where [Multiple TC build agents on a single AWS EC2 instance connected with the Agent Cloud plugin generate new agent names for each run](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000103790-Multiple-TC-build-agents-on-a-single-AWS-EC2-instance-connected-with-the-Agent-Cloud-plugin-generate-new-agent-names-for-each-run) , and the symptoms sound very similar. But in my case, I have only a single build agent running on the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that in the configuration initialization an Amazon marker file is created on path `/opt/buildagent/conf/`, with a name of the format `amazon-i-$ID`.

Standard instructions do not include persisting `/opt/buildagent/conf/` as a volume, but this should solve solve the issue.